# Render HTML inside part of view without effect other tags

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, user-interface, mailkit

Simply I want to render body part of email inside view and my problem is when styles of email body effect on other html part of my page.

```
    <div class="col-md-12 m-b-5">
        <div id="email" dir="ltr">
            @Html.Raw(ViewBag.Body)
        </div>
    </div>
```

I don't know what is render inside email div and want to everything on this just render inside this div not effect other part of page.

Comment: It will not affect other elements on your page

Comment: Depends on the content of @Html.Raw(ViewBag.Body)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Unfortunately it affect other elements and change other styles! we don't know what will render on page by ViewBag.Body

Comment: What affects? Any inline styles that you may have in your `ViewBag.Body` do not affect other elements

Comment: @StephenMuecke Html styles in body of emails is not inline. it is not Law but sometime happens! I have this case to ask this question

Comment: @StephenMuecke it rendered on ViewBag.Body, what can I do with this?  https://pasteboard.co/HCu21am.png

Answer (score 0):

you could just remove all the non valid content before you set the `Viewbag.body` for an outlook plugin i use this code to filter out some of the generated stuff. The issue i had was with embedded images, so i used regular expression to filter them out. perhaps you can do something similar?

```
            var reg = new Regex("<img[^>]+['\"][^>]*>");
            var matches = reg.Matches(message.Body);
            foreach (var match in matches)
            {
                body = body.Replace(match.ToString(), "");
            }
```

**Edit**

when you look at the source of the email (outlook html formated emails) then you see a lot of CSS classes and rules defined at the start of the mail. The actual mail starts with the body tag (screen). so you could just grab the data inside the body tag and display that
[image]

Comment: How to detect non valid content? I don't know what will be in an email. I just want to render that tags only inside email div just like an iframe

Comment: But I want to render styles! render styles only for email body. Is there any html attribute or something else to force styles will render only inside email div. I said something like iframe